# Errors with urlopen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlopen

Good day!

Wrote the following code in python 3 *, which gives a bunch of errors:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
import glob

your_hotel_adres="http://www.booking.com/hotel/ua/boutique-hotel-kavalier.ru.html"

your_hotel_сс1=your_hotel_adres[29:31] 
your_hotel_pagename=''
i = 30
while i <= len(your_hotel_adres):
    i = i + 1
    if your_hotel_adres[i:i+5] == ".html":
        your_hotel_pagename=your_hotel_adres[32:i-3]
        break

your_hotel_comm="http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.ru.html?pagename="+your_hotel_pagename+";cc1="+your_hotel_сс1+";type=total;dist=1;offset=0;rows=1000"
f = urlopen(your_hotel_comm)
```

It should download a webpage and write it to a variable. So I run it, and get lots and lots of errors:

```
    >>> f=urlopen('http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.ru.html?pagename=boutique-hotel
-kavalier;cc1=ua;type=total;dist=1;offset=0;rows=1000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 493, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 676, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 499, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Help me, please!
Just noticed one thing: vbrauzere address of the page that opens, has the form: 
http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.ru.html?pagename=boutique-hotel-kavalier;cc1=ua;type=total;dist=1;offset=0;rows=1000
And address, which generates my code:
http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.ru.html?pagename=boutique-hotel
-kavalier;cc1=ua;type=total;dist=1;offset=0;rows=1000
How to fix it?

Comment: *“HTTP Error 400: Bad Request”* – The server sends this. There is theoretically nothing wrong with your code

Comment: Do you understand what *"HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"* means? How to write the correct request  depends on the site.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian So can You suggest how to write the correct request?

Comment: Visit the site in your browser, perform the desired actions manually and see what requests the browser sends (use browser tools or an external network sniffer to log the http requests), use `urllib.parse.urlencode()` to create the correct query based on the sniffed info.

Comment: Those semicolons `;` in the URL look weird. Should they be ampersands `&` ?

Comment: @Sebastian I thought and tried for an hour. Nothing came of it. Can you please elaborate on the elevation that I should do (I use Google Chrome)?

Comment: you can ask (or read answers to the existing question): "how can I see http requests made by Google Chrome?" (it is probably more suitable for http://superuser.com)

Comment: @Sebastian So I installed Live HTTP Headers and at a block Headers in the first line I saw: 
GET /reviewlist.ru.html?pagename=boutique-hotel-kavalier&cc1=ua&type=total&dist=1&offset=0&rows=1000 HTTP/1.1
And Url was:
http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.ru.html?pagename=boutique-hotel-kavalier&cc1=ua&type=total&dist=1&offset=0&rows=1000
I do not see anything new that could help me.